# How to display a customer's PREVIOUS order ID in a CMS page?

Tags: checkout, orders

Magento CE 1.9.2.2

Trying to fulfill a client's far-fetched request. Their previous developer created a module which allows the success/order confirmation page to be a CMS page which then references a PHTML file within the template. It was meant to facilitate programmatic order creation at a later point in time. For now, to confirm customer orders, it no longer uses success.phtml but an arbitrary file.

To over-simplify the question: **What does it take to echo a customer's most recent order ID on a CMS page?** Inside of this CMS page, it's referencing a core/template PHTML file. I'm able to render any static content from that file without issue but I can't echo any order data.

I attempted to make use of the success.phtml code and several other standard variations without success.

**`<?php $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId()); ?>`**

Then just **echo** **$order->getId()** somewhere but obviously that does not work out of the box.

How would I proceed to call the most recent order information from a CMS page? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use next code to get last customer order (but it will not work for guest orders):

```
$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->joinAttribute('shipping_firstname', 'order_address/firstname', 'shipping_address_id', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('shipping_lastname', 'order_address/lastname', 'shipping_address_id', null, 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId())
            ->addAttributeToFilter('state', array('in' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates()))
            ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
            ->setPageSize('1')
            ->load()

            ;

$order = $orders->getFirstItem()
```

Comment: It will be less resource intensive to add a limit to the collection and only fetch 1 record. Your query will result in all the customer order records.

Comment: Righty, but as practice tell - most customers have only 1 order )) But anyway - you are right. It was just copypaste from "My Recent Orders" block )

Comment: Most customers have only one order is not a very good assumption. Shoukd assume they have 100's and code accordingly 